# Using Query function in Excel to combine data from multiple CSV files into one excel worksheet with each CSV parallel to last?

Tags: excel, function

I have a bunch of csvs each with 2 columns - time and value. Can anyone help me to use MS query to import data from multiple CSV files into one worksheet, with one time column then data from each csv file as a new subsequent column? I've got it to put each CSV dataset into one ginormous worksheet with 1000s of rows so far but no idea how to make it put them next to one another?

Many thanks

Comment: Typically, you are required to post minimal, runnable code to show what you have tried. Not many people will be willing to do the entire work for you. With that, I am going to ask you, what have you tried so far?

Here an article on how to ask questions on Stack Overflow. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @hfontanez I'm asking for help to use the query function in Data section on MS Excel - there's no code needed

Comment: The question remains, what have you tried that is not working or not producing the results you expect?

Comment: I found this article on superuser that might be what you're looking for (or very close) https://superuser.com/questions/1485578/combine-multiple-csv-files-by-column-not-by-row

Comment: @hfontanez I've tried combining and transforming the data, and searching for information on how to put each column next to last rather than below but to no avail